# What's this error in my react project on my codesandbox?

Tags: reactjs, components

I get this error in my project on Codesandbox. While it doesn't get an error on Webstorm:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
> likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
> or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

See my project: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-pateu-hptsrx

But I exported all my components. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Switch` is no longer supported in router v6, you can use `Routes` instead and use `Element` as attribute instead of component.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
    <Route path="/create" element={<Create />} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's fixed. Of course, I'm learning react-router on version 5. So there used `switch` and not used `element`. It seems Codesandbox uses version 6. My question was about another thing that I encountered with this error. Thanks a lot anyway:)